# Docker editing entrypoint of existing container

Tags: docker

I've docker container build from debian:latest image.
I need to execute a bash script that will start several services.
My host machine is Windows 10 and I'm using Docker Desktop, I've found configuration files in
`docker-desktop-data` wsl2 drive in `data\docker\containers\<container_name>`
I've 2 config files there:
config.v2.json and hostcongih.json
I've edited the first of them and replaced:
`"Entrypoint":null` with `"Entrypoint":["/bin/bash", "/opt/startup.sh"]`
I have done it while the container was down, when I restarted it the script was not executed. When I opened config.v2.json file again the Entrypoint was set to null again.

I need to run this script at every container start.
Additional strange thing is that this container doesn't have any volume appearing in docker desktop. I can checkout this container and start another one, but I need to preserve current state of this container (installed packages, files, DB content). How can I change the entrypoint or run the script in other way?
Is there anyway to export the container to image alongside with it's configuration? I need to expose several ports and run the startup script. Is there anyway to make every new container made from the image exported from current container expose the same ports and run same startup script?

Comment: What do you have so far?  Have you looked into orchestration tools like Docker Compose?  I might recommend something like a `docker-compose.yml` file that started multiple containers, maybe from the same image, but overriding the command to run a different single process in each container.

Comment: @DavidMaze I've no experience with orchestration tools. I'm pretty new to Docker as well. I need to setup a deployment environment in Docker container. My environment shall contains PostgreSQL and nginx. I've started a container from debian:latest and installed needed packages. I've exposed needed ports (for db and nginx). I can backup container data, but I need a simple way to start new container with same setup (data + config). Now I figured out how to export config and am checking if it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker's typical workflow involves containers that only run a single process, and are intrinsically temporary.  You'd almost never create a container, manually set it up, and try to persist it; instead, you'd write a script called a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) that describes how to create a reusable *image*, and then launch some number of containers from that.

It's almost always preferable to launch multiple single-process containers than to try to run multiple processes in a single container.  You can use a tool like [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to describe the multiple containers and record the various options you'd need to start them:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml

# Describe the file version.  Required with the stable Python implementation
# of Compose.  Most recent stable version of the file format.
version: '3.8'

# Persistent storage managed by Docker; will not be accessible on the host.
volumes:
  dbdata:

# Actual containers.
services:
  # The database.
  db:
    # Use a stock Docker Hub image.
    image: postgres:15
    # Persist its data.
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    # Describe how to set up the initial database.
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: passw0rd
    # Make the container accessible from outside Docker (optional).
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'  # first port any available host port
                     # second port MUST be standard PostgreSQL port 5432

  # Reverse proxy / static asset server
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23
    # Get static assets from the host system.
    volumes:
      - ./static:/usr/share/nginx/html
    # Make the container externally accessible.
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
```

You can check this file into source control with your application.  Also consider adding a third container that `build:` an image containing the actual application code; that probably will not have `volumes:`.

`docker-compose up -d` will start this stack of containers (without `-d`, in the foreground).  If you make a change to the `docker-compose.yml` file, re-running the same command will delete and recreate containers as required.  Note that you are never running an unmodified `debian` image, nor are you manually running commands inside a container; the `docker-compose.yml` file completely describes the containers, their startup sequences (if not already built into the images), and any required runtime options.

Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for some details about how to make connections between containers: `localhost` from within a container will call out to that same container and not one of the other containers or the host system.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have a question about nginx container, I want to use it to host ASP .NET Core app, can I install .NET packages on this nginx container and export this image to build additional configured containers with this compose?
And what is better (easier and more perspective) to learn Docker Compose or Kubernates?

Comment: Your .NET application should run in its own container, separate from the Nginx container.  Compose is much simpler than Kubernetes and good container practices you learn with Compose will be transferable to a more complex clustered remote Kubernetes environment.